# Show HTML File on Android device exactly as it appears on the MAC

Tags: java, android, html

I have an HTML file which is written in Punjabi (Indian Language) in utf-8. And I am using webview to load the file on the device but when it loads the text appears different than that on the MAC from where it's being copied. I am not sure how to fix this issue, I have tried typeface and change the font but didn't seem to working. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Below is the sample source code.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    WebView webview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/1.html");
}
```

Comment: This could be the internal android web browser's UTF-8 handling, please could you link to the source code, if possible,

Comment: Yes, Please take a look at it now.